# Dynamic require statement is not working in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to dynamically require image in vuejs but it's not working

```
 <div class="card" :style="{ background: 'url(' + require(image) + ')',}">



    export default {
      data() {
      return {
        image: "./assets/dance.jpg",
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image + ')' }">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing the require in the html template, use it in the data.

The reason for this is the fact that Webpack analises all require statements, and resolves them at "compile" time, as opposed when your code is run. This allows webpack to prune away images not used anywhere in your build, or even convert them to data urls.

```
 <div class="card" :style="{ background: 'url(' + image + ')',}">



export default {
    data() {
        return {
            image: require("./assets/dance.jpg"),
        };
    }
};
```

Be aware that requires are resolved from the path where your `.vue` file is located, and not from the root of the project (if you start the path with `@/`, you can refer files from the `src` directory.